# Pronoun gender for proper nouns

Tags: gender, pronoun

Usually I notice that the gender of the pronoun is determined by the gender of the noun.

> Das Mädchen weint. Es ist traurig.
>
> Die Stadt ist schön. Sie gefällt mir.

Is it true that when the noun is a proper noun, we use the gender of the abstraction? For instance, are the sentences

> Ich studiere an der HU. **Sie** (die Uni) ist eine tolle Uni.
>
> Ich mag München. **Sie** (die Stadt)  gefällt mir gut.
>
> Ich war gestern in Frankfurt und habe den Main gesehen. **Er** (der Fluss) ist wunderschön.

correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, the gender (+ number) of the pronoun in the following sentence is determined by the gender of the noun it is referring to. However, there may be some deviations:

> (1) Das Mädchen weint. **Es** ist traurig.
>   (2) Das Mädchen weint. **Sie (?)** ist traurig.

Variant (1) is correct in any case. Sometimes you can read sentences like in (2). Strictly speaking, this is not correct German; however, by some people this variant is preferred to make the pronoun match the sex of the girl.

> (3) Die Stadt ist schön. **Sie** gefällt mir.
>   (4) Die Stadt ist schön. **Es** gefällt mir hier.

Example (3) is correct in any case. You could use the pronoun *es* as in example (4). However here *es* does not refer to the noun *Stadt* but to the general circumstances, an imaginary subject, if you will.

> (5) Ich studiere an der HU. **Sie** ist eine tolle Uni.
>   (6) Ich studiere am KIT. **Es** ist eine tolle Uni.

Here, in (5), *sie* refers to the *HU* which has a female gender because it stands for *Humboldt-Universität* which is female. In example (6), *KIT* is neuter as it is short for *Karlsruher Institut für Technologie* and *Institut* is neuter. So you need the pronoun *es*. As you can see, **not** the "gender of the abstraction" is used but the intrinsic gender of the proper noun.

> (7) Ich mag München. **Es** gefällt mir gut.
>   (8) Ich mag München. **(Not:) Sie** gefällt mir gut.

Variant (7) is correct. *München* has neuter gender, even if you don't recognise it in everyday speech. That *München* is a neuter noun can be seen, for example, if you describe a special epoch of Munich: *Das München der 50er Jahre*. There are some towns that are not neuter (e.g. *der Wedding*; a part of Berlin); but as a rule of thumb you can say that towns in general are neuter. So (7) is correct; (8) is incorrect, even if *München* is a *Stadt*, a female noun.

> (9) In Frankfurt habe ich den Main gesehen. **Er** ist wunderschön.
>   (10) In Frankfurt habe ich die Oder gesehen. **Sie** ist wunderschön.

*Main* and *Oder* are both *Flüsse* and the noun *Fluss* is male. However, rivers have genders which need not be necessarily male. The river *Main* is male; the river *Oder* is female. So in case (9) you have to take the pronoun *er* and in case (10) you have to take the pronoun *sie*, even if the female *Oder* is a (male) *Fluss*.

Answer (score 2):

As personal pronouns stand for nouns, they are supposed to be of matching case, number and gender.

When it comes to proper nouns, it's not that simple:

1. But the first one is not quite one, rather a practical mixture, since it's "head" is a common noun - of which you know the gender.
2. Luckily, cities are always replaced with the neuter personal pronoun(s) - at least I don't know of any exceptions:

   > Ich mag München. Es gefällt mir gut.

   Plural:

   > Wie gefallen dir Wien und Berlin? Sie gefallen mir gut.
3. *Main* has a *historically grown* gender, which coincidentally matches the one of *Fluss*. But there are also feminine rivers (*Wolga*, *Donau*, *Loire*, ...) which have to be replaced with the matching feminine pronoun. So you have to look up/know the Gender, here.

Comment: Thanks! Are there other objects that are replaced by neuter personal pronouns?

Comment: @boaten I really wouldn't know by heart. "Unbelebtheit" is certainly a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Personal pronouns stand for nouns, they always match case, number and gender.

```
Das Mädchen weint. Es (das Mädchen) ist traurig.

Die Stadt ist schön. Sie(die Stadt) gefällt mir.
```

If you now have a noun witch is a proper noun, the case, number and gender matches too:

```
Ich studiere an der HU. Sie (die HU) ist eine tolle Uni.

Ich war gestern in Frankfurt und habe den Main gesehen. Er (der Main) ist wunderschön.
```

There are some special cases, where we can't use Personal pronouns, e.g. Cities without a gender. It's like in english: not "the Miami", jus "Miami", or "the Geneva", just "Geneva". The scentence Grantwalzer said:

```
    Ich mag München. Es gefällt mir gut.
```

is right too, but the "Es" is not a personal pronoun. The meaning is a little bit different, but I can't realy explain. I would say:

```
    Ich mag München. Hier/Dort gefällt es mir gut.
```