# Using gender specific pronouns for inanimate objects

Tags: grammaticality, pronoun, gender, personal-pronoun

I realise that German words have specific genders, but does that apply to pronouns as well?
For example, if I wished to say:

> I searched for my bag, but I didn't find it

Would I say:

> Ich habe meine Tasche gesucht, aber ich habe *es* nicht gefunden.

Or:

> Ich habe meine Tasche gesucht, aber ich habe *sie* nicht gefunden.

Answer (score 74):

Yes, gender applies to pronouns as well. It is a grammatical feature, not a biological.

Correct:

> Ich habe meine Tasche gesucht, aber ich habe **sie** nicht gefunden.

Grammatical gender in English exists only in pronouns (he, she, it), and they are bound to the biological sexus (with some exceptions, like ships which are female too).

But in German each noun has a grammatical gender that sometimes even differs from the biological sexus (if there is a sexus).

And note that the gender is a property of the word, not of the thing named by the word!

---

**Some examples for unanimated objects:**

- masculine

> Das ist **der Löffel, er** liegt auf dem Tisch.
> That's the spoon, it's on the table.

- feminine

> Das ist **die Gabel, sie** liegt auf dem Tisch.
> That's the fork, it's on the table.

- neuter

> Das ist **das Messer, es** liegt auf dem Tisch.
> That's the knife, it's on the table.

---

**Persons:**

- Sexus: male, Gender: masculine

> **Der Mann** isst einen Apfel. **Er** trägt einen Hut.
> The man eats an apple. He wears a hat.

- Sexus: female, Gender: feminine

> **Die Frau** isst einen Apfel. **Sie** trägt einen Hut.
> The woman eats an apple. She wears a hat.

- Sexus: unknown, Gender: neuter

> **Das Kind** isst einen Apfel. **Es** trägt einen Hut.
> The child eats an apple. He/she wears a hat.

In German children are treated as asexual beings. If you want to name the sexus of a child, you use *Junge/Bub* (*boy*) or *Mädchen* (*girl*) (for *Mädchen* see next example)

---

**But sexus and gender do not always match:**

- Sexus: female, Gender: neuter

> **Das Mädchen** isst einen Apfel. **Es** trägt einen Hut.
> The girl eats an apple. She wears a hat.

The word *Mädchen* is a [diminutive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive), which you can see from its postfix *-chen*. And in German all diminutives are always neuter. This is a very strong rule, and it is one of the rare rules that have absolutely no exception. This rule is stronger than the matching between sexus and gender that normally exists in German for persons.

- Sexus: female, Gender: neuter

> **Das Weib** isst einen Apfel. **Es** trägt einen Hut.
> The woman eats an apple. She wears a hat.

The word *Weib* is an old word. Today you use *Frau* instead. But you still find it in the adjective *weiblich* which means *female*. (The word *Weib* is still in use, but it has changed its meaning. Today it has a meaning similar to *vixen/shrew*)

- Sexus: male, Gender: feminine

> **Die Tunte** isst einen Apfel. **Sie** trägt eine Federboa.
> The drag queen eats an apple. He wears a feather boa.

---

German is a living language, which means, that its rules are changing over the time. What I told you about *Mädchen, Weib, Tunte* and some more nouns where sexus and gender do not match, is still correct. But in the last 50 years, German native speakers began to use pronouns that don't match with the grammatical gender, but with the biological sexus, and since a few decades this is even considered to be correct too.

So today you are also allowed to say this:

> **Das Mädchen** isst einen Apfel. **Sie** trägt einen Hut.
> **Das Weib** isst einen Apfel. **Sie** trägt einen Hut.
> **Die Tunte** isst einen Apfel. **Er** trägt eine Federboa.

But note that the matching of the pronoun with the grammatical gender still is correct too, so in this case, you can choose.

---

**Examples for the same thing (a car) that has different names with different genders:**

- masculine

> **Der Wagen** ist rostig. **Er** steht in der Garage.
> The car is rusty. It is in the garage.

- feminine

> **Die Karre** ist rostig. **Sie** steht in der Garage.
> The car is rusty. It is in the garage.

- neuter

> **Das Auto** ist rostig. **Es** steht in der Garage.
> The car is rusty. It is in the garage.

As you can see, the gender is a property of the word, not of the thing. It is the very same rusty old limousine we are talking about here, but since we use different nouns with different genders, we also must change the pronoun.

(*Der Wagen* is often used for a bigger car, like a limousine. *Die Karre* is often used for an old and shabby car. *Das Auto* is the general translation of *the car*.)

Comment: Unfortunately, one could only upvote once.

Comment: "Das ist der Löffel**. E**r liegt auf dem Tisch." Possibly a semicolon might be okay, but a comma seems wrong.

Comment: @Roland Comma between two main clauses is completely correct; it is merely a matter of style whether you prefer a full stop, a semicolon or a comma.

Comment: @Florian OK, I was wrong. But it would be nice if it was at least consistent in the answer.

Comment: *In German children are treated as **asexual** beings:* doesn't that foil what you said about the difference between *sexus* and (grammatical) *gender*? Their grammatical neutral gender shouldn't mean have no biological 'sexus'. Otherwise one could similiarly argue that *Mädchen* is treated as 'asexual' which you explicitly deny.

Comment: *But in the last 50 years, German native speakers began to use pronouns that don't match with the grammatical gender, but with the biological sexus, and since a few decades this is even considered to be correct too.* This claim is false. The *constructio ad sensum* goes back all the way to OHG. For instance, Behaghel, *Deutsche Syntax*, vol. 3., p. 38 quotes Otfrid von Weißenburg: *zi **themo** selben wibe, **thiu** erist deta sina kunft kund.* The same pages has quotes going up to the 18th century, see [here](https://www.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/view/bsb11023510?page=56).

Comment: In Grimm‘s fairytales, for instance, one frequently encounters _es_ references to female but neutral _Weib_, _Mädchen_, _Schneewittchen/Schneeweißchen_, _Dornröschen_ or _Aschenputtel_ over many sentences. This sounds strange to modern ears. Grammatical gender agreement is now limited to the same sentence and not mandatory there either. Natural agreement is **always** allowed for personal pronouns.

Comment: PS: Uneasy _es_ references happen for males as well in Grimm‘s, e.g. _Rumpelstilzchen_, _Schneiderlein_, _Männchen_, _Brüderchen_. I forgot to mention popular _Rotkäppchen_.

Comment: In the two novels about *Heidi* by Johanna Spyri the littel girl Heidi is consequently always referred to by the neuter pronoun *es* (never by *sie*) and you also often find *"das Heidi"* but never *"die Heidi"* in these books. So, the title of the second book is not »Heidi kann brauchen, was *sie* gelernt hat« but [Heidi kann brauchen, was **es** gelernt hat](https://www.amazon.de/Heidi-kann-brauchen-was-gelernt/dp/3791535471)

Comment: @Crissov: Most of the examples you quote were already addressed in the posting: "-chen" signifies a diminutive and diminutives are always neutral! It is "die Maid" but "das Mädchen" quite like it is "der Bub" but "das Bübchen".

Answer (score 7):

Yes, the pronoun has to reflect the gender and there is no fallback to neuter. Look up in case of doubt, especially for countries and rivers.

There is one further special case. If a person is involved, the pronoun increasingly uses the sex instead of the grammatical gender in case of difference:

> Das Mädchen ging in den Wald. **Es** hatte ein Kleid an.

While this is grammatically fine, the more intuitive:

> Sie hatte ein Kleid an.

is no longer unconditionally considered as errror.

Comment: I thought city names were always neuter, so it would not be necessary to look up the gender for each city. This was mentioned as a rule with no apparent exceptions in the answers to [What are the relative pronouns of cities?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30830/what-are-the-relative-pronouns-of-cities)

Comment: Ich wette in älteren Texten wirst Du keinen Wechsel des Geschlechts von "das Mädchen" zu "sie" finden. Bei einem zweiten, weiblichen Hauptwort ist die Aussage nach wie vor unzweideutig: "Das Mädchen ging in die Halle. Sie war dunkel und groß."

Answer (score 2):

the correct sentence would be:

Ich habe meine Tasche gesucht, aber ich habe sie nicht gefunden.

Or:

Ich habe meine Tasche gesucht, habe sie aber nicht gefunden.